# How can I serialize and deserialize list of my custom type in correct way in Python json?

Tags: python, json, json-deserialization, json-serialization, custom-type

This is my custom type

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, pid, institute, profession, group, educationalLevel, age, gpa):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.pid = pid
        self.institute = institute
        self.profession = profession
        self.group = group
        self.educationalLevel = educationalLevel
        self.age = age
        self.gpa = gpa
```

Can you describe what it should be implemented to json serialize and deserialize list of that type in Python?

Comment: Does your class have anything else in it? If not you might as well just use a dictionary.

Comment: Do you have a particular serialisation in mind? Do you have any examples of what you have tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: @AlexHall No, only this information. Could you please provide an example with dictionary? I don't fully understand it.

Comment: `student = dict(name='Foo'); json_string = json.dumps(student); student2 = json.loads(json_string); assert student == student2`

Comment: @AlexHall I have tried your version, it is okey. But when I desirialize json, it occurs json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 44 (char 43).
Json file looks like: 
`{"name": "Foo", "surname": "Dinglage", "age": 1}{"name": "Optimus", "surname": "Octava", "age": 2}{"name": "John", "surname": "Lol", "age": 3}`
Is any way to fix it?

Comment: Are you the one writing to the file? If so then you should put the dicts in a list first. Don't save multiple separate values in JSON.